# Image swap for Mobile using jumbotron bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

What is the most efficient way to swap out an image for mobil when using a jumbotron in bootstrap? I dont like the way the image looks on mobil size when using img-responsive. I have spent all day researching srcet and find that it does not provide a solution any better than img-responsive. There has to be a way to swap out images on different devices.

Here is the site I am working on http://janeanesanborn.com/home.htm

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using the `background-image:url('pic.jpg')` CSS property instead of the HTML element. That way you can change it based on responsive media queries.

Comment: Thank you Rachel for responding. I was trying to avoid that by using bootstrap but I think it is probably the best way too.